# apache.commons.math3 - how to use linear programming?

Tags: java, apache, math, linear-programming

commons-math (ver. 2.2) had an LP solver.

[Here](https://michaelmadhukalya.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/solving-linear-programming-lp-problems-using-java/) I found the follow example code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.GoalType;
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.OptimizationException;
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.RealPointValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear.LinearConstraint;
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear.LinearObjectiveFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear.Relationship;
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear.SimplexSolver;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Main {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //describe the optimization problem
        LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(new double[] { 3, 5}, 0);

        Collection constraints = new ArrayList();
        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 2, 8}, Relationship.LEQ, 13));
        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 5, -1}, Relationship.LEQ, 11));

        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 1, 0}, Relationship.GEQ, 0));
        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 0, 1}, Relationship.GEQ, 0));

        //create and run solver
        RealPointValuePair solution = null;
        try {
            solution = new SimplexSolver().optimize(f, constraints, GoalType.MAXIMIZE, false);
        }
        catch (OptimizationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (solution != null) {
            //get solution
            double max = solution.getValue();
            System.out.println("Opt: " + max);

            //print decision variables
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                System.out.print(solution.getPoint()[i] + "\t");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when adding the maven dependency of the latest math version (3.6.1)

I see most related classes are deprecated, and I haven't found any code examples for the updated versions.

Would be glad to use 3.6.1 for my LP problems - can someone assist here please?

Comment: Just because something is deprecated doesn't mean it can't be used. But there's probably a reason stated somewhere **why** they're deprecated. Keep reading and you'll learn the secrets of that library.

Comment: Perhaps if you post an example of something you are trying to do (with the deprecated API), someone may help you find the non-deprecated way.

Answer (score 10):

The example from the link is using *commons-math* version 2.

The main package from commons math seems to change from version 2 `org.apache.commons.math` to `org.apache.commons.math3` in version 3.

The classes used in the example are from `org.apache.commons.math.optimization` package, in this concret case the package in the new version is [`org.apache.commons.math3.optim`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html?overview-summary.html).

The sample code from version 2, to version 3 looks like:

```
package commons.math;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.LinearConstraint;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.LinearConstraintSet;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.LinearObjectiveFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.Relationship;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.GoalType;

public class MathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //describe the optimization problem
        LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(new double[] { 3, 5}, 0);

        Collection<LinearConstraint> constraints = new ArrayList<LinearConstraint>();
        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 2, 8}, Relationship.LEQ, 13));
        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 5, -1}, Relationship.LEQ, 11));

        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 1, 0}, Relationship.GEQ, 0));
        constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 0, 1}, Relationship.GEQ, 0));

        //create and run solver
        PointValuePair solution = null;
        solution = new SimplexSolver().optimize(f, new LinearConstraintSet(constraints), GoalType.MAXIMIZE);

        if (solution != null) {
            //get solution
            double max = solution.getValue();
            System.out.println("Opt: " + max);

            //print decision variables
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                System.out.print(solution.getPoint()[i] + "\t");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Does this solver use all CPU cores?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko actually I don't know it, however it's an interesting question, maybe you can post a new one asking for this.